# How to force onClick event with Selenium?

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I am testing an application that have the following html code:

```
...
<input 
    type="button"
    class="picto modif"
    onclick="hideDiv('divGlobalResult');showDiv('divForm')"
/>
```

When the user clicks on this button, the div `divGlobalResult` is hidden and the div `divForm` is shown.

I want to simulate this action with Selenium. Here is how I did:

```
focus      css=input.picto.modif
fireEvent  css=input.picto.modif  click
```

However, the `divForm` appears while the second div `divGlobalResult` stays on the screen...

What am I missing?

---

```
function hideDiv(idDivElement) {
    $("#" + idDivElement).css("display", "none");
}

function showDiv(idDivElement) {
    $("#" + idDivElement).css("display", "");
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like it SHOULD work, but I wonder if the semi-colons are having an issue in the event.
Was there a reason you didn't do a tradition click command?

Also, do these events fire correctly when you try this manually?

Comment: Using a tradition click command is an interesting option. Manually, the events fire correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats happening because Selenium click function cannot simulate a real "Click" action performed with the mouse.

I have also faced this problem and the solution that best suited me was to take control of the mouse by using java robot and performing the click with it.

I hope this helps.